# VS Code - ReferenceError: $ is not defined WHY?

Tags: javascript, json, debugging, visual-studio-code, config

I am working on udacity design patters course. There are giving materials and I have implemented some onto it then tried to debugging. However it gives me the error saying I have no linked to jQuery even though it had been defined as

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/retain.js"></script>
```

on separate index.html file

Because the files were provided by the course, it should be written correctly. So I must do something beforehand...

I am new to JS code, searched & going through many videos but still have no ideas: (I have set config.json (as asked on introduction video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6cOsxaNC06c&t=103s). I would be appreciated if anyone can help in anyway! (or anyone can direct me to good tutorials of debugging on VS Code ). Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this a runtime error or an error in VS Code?

Comment: This is VS code error, it cannot recognize $.

Comment: Can you please explain what that means. Are you not seeing the expected suggestions on `$` or is there another error?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, 
when I run debugging on JS, it throws error as ---

Exception has occurred: Error
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/satokoichimura/Document/Cat_Click_Premium/js/app.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)

Comment: That looks like an error with your code. How are you starting the debugger? If you are starting debugging on just that file, jquery will not be loaded since its only referenced from the html file

Comment: Aaa, thank you for being patient with me. I will have a look into launch.json file. I just went through the video only but not understanding what it does. Thank you. How can I give you up vote / reputation? May be you can put your comment as answer?

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that I had no idea what I was doing. Now I know I cannot debug anything for JS frontend only project, all I could do was just go to development tool to see where a bug can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had no idea what I was doing. Now I know there is no debug tool for JS frontend only project, all I can do is just go to development tool or usual console.log to see where a bug could be. Phew.

Comment: VS Code [does support debugging front-end JavaScript just fine](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_debug-client-side). Take a look at the [Debugger for chrome extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome) for example, which shows how to configure `launch.json` for webpages

Comment: @MattBierner, sorry forgot to say thanks for long time!!

Answer (score 2):

## Debugger `type` should be `Chrome`

There's a configuration file under the ".vscode" folder, named "launch.json" which allows you to select the type of environment where your debugger needs to run. If you select your debugger type as "Chrome" you should be able to debug the script browser-side on Chrome.

*.vscode/launch.json*

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch index.html",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "file": "${workspaceFolder}/index.html"
    }
  ]
}
```